# How to start a new activity from a WakeReminderIntentService

Tags: android

I have a following code like this.
            public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {

```
public ReminderService() {
    super("ReminderService");
        }

@Override
void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("ReminderService", "Doing work.");
    Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
     }
                              }
```

How can I start a new activity from this file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that the WakeReminderIntentService is, but if you are in a Service you can simply use startActivity(Intent intent).

The documentation is on: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29